# Open a modal form with validation when clicking on a button in Bootstrap

Tags: javascript, forms, twitter-bootstrap, validation

I have a `.container` > `.row` > `.col-*-4` (3x)

Inside each column I have a share button. I need that button to pop-up a modal with a form with validation conditions.

**For Example**:

Please enter your name (must be at least one upper letter, 2 characters long, full name)

- Natalya Smooth (correct)
- natalya S (incorrect)

How can I do this?

Comment: This is a lot of requests put together.  What have you done so far?  Can you get a [modal](http://getbootstrap.com/javascript/#modals) up and running?  I'd try to break up what you need so it's clear.

Comment: Please do not vandalize your posts. If you believe your question is not useful or is no longer useful, it should be *deleted* instead of editing out all of the data that actually makes it a question. By posting on the Stack Exchange network, you've granted a non-revocable right for SE to distribute that content (under the CC BY-SA 3.0 license). By SE policy, any vandalism will be reverted.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `pattern` for the your text field:

```
<form >
  Name: 
  <input type="name" name="nm" pattern="(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z]).{2,}" 
         title="Must contain at one uppercase and at least 2 or more characters">
  <input type="submit">
</form>
```